# Spring boot onAuthenticationFailure is not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, authorization

I believe the problem is when I login with the wrong password, i get redirected to /login?error=true (so I think the onAuthenticationFailure part is working), however there is no message, meaning message.badCredentials is not displayed.

In the eclipse IDE I see this error:

> Error resolving template [login_null], template might not exist or
> might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I think this is because the request mapping for /login is always being executed even on the error page since the url still contains /login. I am not sure of what I can do to fix this. Any suggestions would be apreciated!

```
   @Override
   public void onAuthenticationFailure(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
       setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=true");

       super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);

       final Locale locale = localeResolver.resolveLocale(request);

       String errorMessage = messages.getMessage("message.badCredentials", null, locale);

       if (exception.getMessage()
           .equalsIgnoreCase("User is disabled")) {
           errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.disabled", null, locale);
       } else if (exception.getMessage()
           .equalsIgnoreCase("User account has expired")) {
           errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.expired", null, locale);
       } else if (exception.getMessage()
           .equalsIgnoreCase("blocked")) {
           errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.blocked", null, locale);
       } else if (exception.getMessage()
           .equalsIgnoreCase("unusual location")) {
           errorMessage = messages.getMessage("auth.message.unusual.location", null, locale);
       }
```

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll().antMatchers("/checkExists").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll().antMatchers("/enableAdmin").permitAll().antMatchers("/login").permitAll().antMatchers("/login?lang=en")
                .permitAll().antMatchers("/signup").permitAll().antMatchers("/success").permitAll().antMatchers("/u/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("ADMIN").antMatchers("/python/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER,ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/reports/**").hasAnyAuthority("USER,ADMIN").antMatchers("/dashboard/**")
                .hasAnyAuthority("USER,ADMIN").anyRequest().authenticated().and().csrf().disable().formLogin().loginPage("/login?lang=en").loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .successHandler(customizeAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true").failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler).usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("password").and().logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/").and()
                .exceptionHandling();
    }
```

```
        public ModelAndView login(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
            String lang = request.getParameter("lang");
            //System.out.println(lang);
            modelAndView.setViewName("login_" + lang);
            return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: The error message seems to be not used in any way. You can use the error message in the request param in the Defaut Failure URL and move down this -> super.onAuthenticationFailure(request, response, exception);
to the end of the function. Debug that method will help understand the flow

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what you mean exactly